# Raise anchor ng-click on enter keypress for accessibility in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am working on a problem for accessibility issues in my project. One scenario I am struggling is, we have anchor tag with ng-click event. When someone is hitting tab and reached anchor tag on the page using keyboard, they are hitting enter key, and they think it should do something. But, unfortunately enter key and click events works well with button control but not with anchor. Anyone has any suggestions how to solve this problem?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, and resolved it be creating a simple directive which would intercept the keydown/keypress events on a link, and then call a function associated with the directive.

Here is the directive:

```
 // Allows for the interception of the enter key, and then calling a passed in function
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app.directives')
        .directive('convEnter', convEnter);

    function convEnter() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link
        };
        return directive;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('keydown keypress', function (event) {
                if (event.which === 13) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.$eval(attrs.convEnter, { 'event': event });
                    });

                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

To use it, you would simply apply it to your link, ie:

```
<a conv-enter="vm.click()" ng-click="vm.click()">Click Link</a>
```

Of course this is a bit repetitive as you are specifying "vm.click()" twice;  you could optimize this if desired by having the directive simply call the "click" function on the element itself, as long as you always wanted the click and the enter key to invoke the same function.  (In my scenario, I sometimes needed to distinguish between the two, and hence i allowed passing in a separate function)